# Dc.js bar graph bars too wide for x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've been having a problem with a bar chart I created using `dc.js` in that the bars on the bar graph are too wide for the x-axis causing some ugly overflow.

Here is a picture of when I'm using `.xUnits(dc.unit.ordinal)` in my code:

[image: Overflowing Bars]

Here is a picture of when I'm using `.xUnits(function() { return 10})` in my code:

[image]

Here's the code in which I generate the chart

```js
function makeGraph(error, pubJson)
{
    pubChart = dc.barChart("#publication-chart");
    var pubData = pubJson;
    var pubCrossfilter = crossfilter(pubJson);
    var pubDimension = pubCrossfilter.dimension(function(data)
    {   
        return data.PlaceOfPub; //will read in all occurances of publication. Cannot be acted upon
    });
    var pubGroup = pubDimension.group().reduceCount();
    var pubGroupFiltered = groupFilter(pubGroup);

    pubChart
        .width(1280)
        .height(350)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Amsertdam", "Cambridge", "Dublin", "Edinburgh", "Unknown", "Geneva", "Glasgow", "Lugano", "Oxford", "Paris", "The Hague"])) // Need empty val to offset first value
        .xUnits(function() {return 10})
        .margins({top: 10, right: 40, bottom : 30, left : 40})
        .brushOn(false)
        .yAxisLabel("Number of Books Written in Country")   
        .xAxisLabel("Cities")
        .dimension(pubDimension)
        .group(pubGroupFiltered)
        //.ordering(function(d) {return d.value})
        .label(function(d){ return d.data.key + " : " + d.data.value});

    pubChart.render();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - why don't you want your `xUnits` to match your scale? `xUnits` is mainly for the bar width.

Comment: Or are you talking about the way "The Hague" is halfway off the X axis in the first screenshot? Please clarify the exact problem you're trying to solve, because the second screenshot is so wildly wrong that it's difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's the bars going over the axis that's the problem. Sorry about the vagueness

Comment: Okay, sure, makes sense now. `xUnits` definitely won't help with that because it's a scale domain issue. I'm not sure but I think this problem goes straight to d3. However I'll see if there are any workarounds.

Comment: Hmm, the [canonical ordinal bar chart example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/ordinal-bar.html) doesn't exhibit this problem. I don't see anything weird in your code.. are you using dc.js 2.1?

Comment: I uninstalled Dc.js and started again and the axis problem was gone when I reinstalled so I guess something had went wrong when I originally installed it. Sorry for the anti climax but thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ah that's great. Must have been an old version. Thanks for following up!